# How to use Jenkins JobDSL to set 'Check out to specific local branch' in Git Plugin?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-job-dsl

I have the following:

```
job {
  scm {
    git {
      remote {
        url(GIT_URL)
      }
      branch('master')
    }
  }
}
```

It works pretty well but I would like for it to set 'Check out to specific local branch' to 'master'. How is that done?

I didn't find anything in https://github.com/jenkinsci/git-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/hudson/plugins/git/GitSCM.java that pointed to anything that can be used but I may have missed something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That option is currently not supported by the Job DSL, but you can use a [configure block](https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin/wiki/The-Configure-Block) to modify the generated config XML:

```
job {
  scm {
    git {
      remote {
        url(GIT_URL)
      }
      branch('master')
      configure { node ->
        node / 'extensions' << 'hudson.plugins.git.extensions.impl.LocalBranch' {
          localBranch('master')
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Since the accepted answer was written, support for 'Check out to specific local branch' has been added:

```
job {
  scm {
    git {
      remote {
        url(GIT_URL)
      }
      branch('master')

      extensions {
        localBranch 'master'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is yet another way of doing the named local branch:

```
multibranchPipelineJob(pathToJob) {
    branchSources { ... }
    configure {
        def traits = it / sources / data / 'jenkins.branch.BranchSource' / source / traits
        traits << 'jenkins.plugins.git.traits.LocalBranchTrait' {
            localBranch('**')
        }
    }
}
```